# Make sure text's double quotation is closed

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I make sure the input text from user that starts with double quotation also ends with double quotation? or it has a double quotation in the text make sure it is closed like:

1. `test"a` wrong
2. `test"a"` correct
3. `"test'` wrong
4. `"test"` correct

I have a delegate function on key up event so if the user start with `"` it should not run the function until the double quotation is closed otherwise the API that I pass the value throws an error because the quotation is not closed, but they can also input text without the quotations.

 I have tried regex but is there a better way you ?

```
if (filterDescriptor.value && String(filterDescriptor.value).startsWith('"') ) {
    if(!String(filterDescriptor.value).match('"([^\\"]|\\")*"')) {
        filterDescriptor.value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you manually modify the input entered by the user and add quotes at start and end. if it's compulsory to pass quoted text into API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
if (filterDescriptor.value
    && String(filterDescriptor.value).startsWith('"')
    && String(filterDescriptor.value).slice(-1) === '"'
) {
    doSomething();
}
```

These are also optons:

`&& String(filterDescriptor.value).substr(-1) === '"'`

or

`&& String(filterDescriptor.value).charAt(String(filterDescriptor.value).length - 1) === '"'`

### Update

To check if a string contains two quotation marks, you can try this method using JavaScript functions:

`String(filterDescriptor.value).includes('"',String(filterDescriptor.value).search('"') + 1)`

Or using RegEx:

`RegExp('.*".*".*').test(filterDescriptor.value.toString())`

Comment: This is a good solution but it just hit me what if the user inputs something like `a"a`, it doesnt start with `"` so its the second character, should I use regular expression in this case?

Comment: Depeneds on what your expected/required user input is. The answer is for the question as stated: the user has to start with double quotes, and the function should run when double quotes are closed. If the criteria is different, the solution may also be different.

Comment: right, your answer was perfect for my requirement I stated initially but I just added another requirement that just realized I have to consider.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way, you can check the last character like this :

```
filterDescriptor.value.toString().charAt(filterDescriptor.value.toString().length-1);
```

It will give you the last char in string so you can validate this.

And for validating it's not good to make the field empty, it's better to show an error or warning to user.

Comment: `charAt(filterDescriptor.value.toString().length-2)`` will return the character one before last, not the last one